# Does Selenium work with Oracle based websites?

Tags: python, oracle, selenium

I'm a recent self-learner of Python, so please be gentle!

I recently went through the 'Automate the boring stuff with Python' course on Udemy, and now trying to implement my own project.

I have a website that I need to access fairly regularly for work and looking to automate my navigation using Selenium.

I've got the navigation to and log-in down, that works (using find_element_by...) no problem.

I then got stuck quite quickly when trying to select sub-pages from drop down menus, no matter what I tried I recieved errors saying the object / id / css selector etc and got the unable to locate element exception. There is a submenu on the left side of the website, and I've tried using the visible text option to select it, but that's not worked either.

The website is built / supplied by (?) Oracle - is that causing me the issue?

A bit disheartneing that I got stuck so soon!

Thanks in advance

Rich

Comment: Where's  the page url, or source code, and your python code?

Comment: It's not that the websites built with Oracle can't be scraped. You should put your code here so that we can help you properly. It's possibly the problem in your code only. Hope you understand.